# Accessibility options - "Home answers calls"

Tags: accessibility

I like this option on my old Android 4.2 Samsung Galaxy S3 mini. Especially when I am driving it's much easier to press a button instead of sliding...

But I cannot find such option neither on Android 4.4 phones (different phones, from Motorola to Sona) nor on newer phones with Android 5.1 and 6.0.

Is it 4.2 option that is not part of newer Android version?

Answer (score 0):

Only Samsung offers that feature like home button answers the call. For other phone their might be an option like this, but not necessary to have.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, As said previously: It is device specific feature. But you may have this by using a custom ROM which provides this feature. Lineage ROMs usually provide this feature.
Google: "[Your device model] custom rom xda"